# Can we make 2 sidebar navigation drawer in 1 mobile application?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I would like to ask whether we can make 2 different sidebar navigation drawers in 1 mobile application? For example, if user logs in as a student, it will go to the student navigation drawer page and if a user logs in as a lecturer, it will go to the lecturer navigation drawer interface. Can anyone give me idea, so that the whole story gets more clear? What coding should I put in the **sign up** and **login** page to differentiate whether the user signs up / logins as a student or lecturer? FYI, right know I've already done the navigation drawer for the student only and now I still think about making the 2nd navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask them if they want to sign app as a student or lecturer.
And related to navigation drawer, what about you make only 1 navigation drawer with 2 menus
and add menu programmatically at runtime depending on if the user is lecturer or student.

```
if(user.getType() == User.LECTURER){

// add lecturer menu to navigation drawer

}else if(user.getType() == User.STUDENT){

// add student menu to navigation drawer

}
```

an alternative way is to make 2 activities depending on the condition above ? so you get less code in an activity.

Comment: Okay. Should I make  a choice in the sign up interface? Like adding radio button, so the user can choose whether as a student or lecturer. it is ok?

Comment: Yea, I guess so